# Disallow publishing of debug builds for ClickOnce deployment

Tags: clickonce

Is there a way to disallow publishing of debug builds with ClickOnce?

I only want to allow release builds through, but right now human error causes a debug build to slip through once in a while.

We're publishing the build from within Visual Studio.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I have started to modify the .csproj files to include the following code to throw an error for debug deploys, effectively preventing the deploy from happening:

```
<!-- The following makes sure we don’t try to publish a configuration that defines the DEBUG constant -->
<Target Name="BeforePublish">
    <Error Condition="'$(DebugSymbols)' == 'true'" Text="You attempted to publish a configuration that defines the DEBUG constant!" />
</Target>
```

Just place it at the end of the file, right before the `</Project>` tag.

(original source: http://www.nathanpjones.com/wp/2010/05/preventing-clickonce-publishing-a-debug-configuration/comment-page-1/#comment-625)

Comment: I like this answer because a) it relies on the symbol being defined instead of the build being used and b) it doesn't presuppose a .bat being used to build

Comment: This is the best answer and doesn't require a batch file or some NuGet package to operate. I have further tweaked it so that all publishes must be Release/AnyCPU or it'll fail.
`<Target Name="BeforePublish">
  <Error Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Release' Or '$(PlatformName)' != 'AnyCPU'" Text="You attempted to publish a configuration that is not Release and AnyCPU architecture!" />
</Target>`

Comment: chuck: it works as expected. However, element "Error" is not defined in the schema for "Target", http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/t50z2hka.aspx. Has element "Error" been deprecated? However, it is in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b08t3s4.aspx.

Comment: To prevent to the error number field from being empty in the error message from MSBuild ("... .vbproj(245,5): error : You attempted to publish ..."), use element "Code", e.g. "<Target Name="BeforePublish"> <Error Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Release' Or '$(PlatformName)' != 'AnyCPU'" Code="9999" Text="You attempted to publish a configuration that is not Release and AnyCPU architecture!" /> </Target>". The error message would then be "... .vbproj(245,5): error 9999: You attempted to publish ..."

Comment: I implemented the solution a couple of months ago and it just saved me (I used chuck's solution). I came back to this answer just to make sure I upvoted. I also really feel the need to give someone a high five.

Answer (score 9):

One thing you can do is add a condition to the .csproj or .vbproj file that MSBuild will check when doing a build.

The condition would check if a publish is occurring and check if the build is a debug build, then do something like run an external tool or otherwise interrupt the build process or cause it to fail.

An example might be something like this:

```
<Choose>
    <When Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='Debug' ">
        <Exec Command="C:\foo.bat" ContinueOnError="false" />
    </When>
 </Choose>
```

Where foo.bat is a batch file that return non-zero, thus stopping the publish from occurring.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: Have a look at MSBuild conditional examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164307.aspx

Comment: Has ever anyone acomplished that and is willing to share the solution?

Comment: Just added an example. Haven't tested, but should give you the general idea.

Answer (score 3):

I have chosen another solution that worked for me:

I couldn't change my build process. So I did *Tools* → *Customize...* and change the text of the action, adding an alert like "Publish [CONFIGURE TO RELEASE!]", and placing the Publish button next to the Debug/Release configuration option. It's easy!

With this I considerably reduced the risk of human error. Those buttons should always be together.