# Prevent deploying debug build with ClickOnce

Tags: c#, deployment, clickonce, visual-studio-debugging

I'm publishing a ClickOnce application with VS2008, but before every publish I have to switch to Release config manually. This is fine as far as I don't forget to switch. Is there a way to prevent deploying debug builds ? Is there some compiler directive like:

```
#if DEBUG
#if ClickOnce
#error You cannot publish a debug build
#endif
#endif
```

Or is there a way (without build scripts) to automatically switch to Release config before publishing ?

(I've found some similar questions but didn't like the anwsers on them)

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't it already prompt you that *something doesn't match up* and ask for confirmation before overriding when you try to publish a debug build over a release build (with no such dialog when publishing the correct version)?

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately no, there is no such dialog.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47107/clickonce-disallow-publishing-of-debug-builds which provides a link to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164307.aspx

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47107/clickonce-disallow-publishing-of-debug-builds/15080048#15080048 (the best answer is below the accepted one, though).

Comment: Yes, thanks. That is the accepted answer here as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is frowned upon, but please see my answer in the related thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15080048/571237

*In short you can modify the project files to check for debug symbols before publishing, and throw an error condition if they're found. This prevents the deploy from happening without needing any .bat files or external processing.*

Comment: Thanks, the addin worked fine but everybody had to install it. Now I can use:
<Target Name="BeforePublish">
    <Error Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Release'" Text="You can only publish a Release build!" />
  </Target>

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I've found so far is to write a vs2008 add-in based on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165638.aspx

```
    public void OnPublishBegin(ref bool pubContinue)
    {
        if (pubContinue && _applicationObject.Solution.SolutionBuild.ActiveConfiguration.Name != "Release")
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You can only publish a Release build");
            pubContinue = false;
        }
    }
```

Any other ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Great suggestion!  Fixes my problem and allows me to add other useful features.